# Lubuntu 14.04 desktop will not load after automatic update

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

Since the last automatic update my account is basically gone.

When I log in all I see is the mouse and the default desktop image, but no panel, no icons, and not even the Terminal will work, it's as if the explorer.exe on windows never loaded (something that is in charge of loading the GUI).

When I open the guest account and open firefox it works for a moment but then it freezes.

Any ideas? I have some files I hope to recover but would like to restore the account itself.

**EDIT:** Due to lack of time I had to give up, aborted drive in a perilous escape. I guess I'll disable Automatic Updates for now, they tend to be a hassle for me being ignorant on kernels.

Comment: The last update for me was a kernel update. Could you try using the previous kernel? That should still be on your system and you should be able to select it from the GRUB screen.

Comment: The grub screen always came up with only two options and I tried them both (Ubuntu and Recovery mode), is there something I need to edit on the Grub before booting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some times your desktop may not load due to problem with `lightdm`.
*Make sure you are connected to internet with DHCP on.*
press CTRL + ALT + F4 then login using your username and password

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Now  type `sudo shutdown -r now` to restart.

Comment: I got `404 not found` on the apt-get update, and I checked my router settings it says DHCP server is enabled whatever that means.

Also tried it directly from the modem itself with the LAN... not sure if modem has DHCP disabled. =/

Comment: 'DHCP on' means that you dont have to enter ip address to connect to connect to internet. you just plugin to ethernet or connect to wifi and just start browsing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Lubuntu, but I assume it has a **Unity** desktop shell.

When booted without Unity, press Ctrl+Alt+F2 and login.

Then type in the following commands then hit Enter after each.

```
      `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

      `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

      `setsid unity`

      `unity --reset-icons`
```

Did it work?

Comment: Thanks, but on the second command I got this error:
    `error: Cannot autolaunch D-bus without X11 $DISPLAY`

Comment: I had to abort mission, backed up files onto another lubuntu boot drive and started from scratch. Thanks again though.